# JPA/Hibernate @ManyToMany not creating index on the join table

Tags: hibernate, indexing, many-to-many, jpa-2.0, join

Please consider the following two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILE")
public class Profile extends BaseEntity {

private Long id;
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "taggedProfiles")
public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAG", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "TAG_ID", "USERS_ID" }))
public class Tag extends BaseEntity {
private Long id;

private List<Profile> taggedProfiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "PROFILE_TAG", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID"), 
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                columnNames = {"PROFILE_ID", "TAG_ID" }))
// @ForeignKey(name = "FK__TAG__PROFILE", inverseName = "FK__PROFILE__TAG")
// @Index(name = "IDX__PROFILE__PROFILE_ID")
public List<Profile> getTaggedProfiles() {
    return taggedProfiles;
}

/**
 * @param taggedProfiles
 *            the taggedProfiles to set
 */
public void setTaggedProfiles(List<Profile> taggedProfiles) {
    this.taggedProfiles = taggedProfiles;
}
}
```

The join table, `PROFILE_TAG` gets created fine, however, no index is created, I was hoping hibernate will create a composite index on the join table. What gives?

Comment: Correction: Hibernate should mark the two columns as composite primary key which in turn would create a clustered index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the type from `List` to `Set` did the trick:

Changed:

```
private List<Profile> taggedProfiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();
```

To:

```
private Set<Profile> taggedProfiles = new HashSet<Profile>();
```